# can't run report-designer.bat file in Pentaho 3.7 version

Tags: node.js, java-8, pentaho

[Image of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38fPu.png)

I am trying to use Pentaho reporting tool (Version - 3.7). For that, I installed Java SE Development Kit 8 (1.8.0). When I am trying to run the report-designer.bat file, I got an error as show in the picture. Anyone can please help me?

Comment: seems like it is not able to find JAVA_Home path..
just make sure that in environment variable you have setted java_home properly.

Comment: Also, afaik, that version of PRD only works properly with java 6. If you want to use java 8 use a more recent version (current is 8.0 or 8.1)